# gitignore template for Xcode, IntelliJ Idea and Phonegap (aka Cordova)

Tags: xcode, git, cordova

Does anyone have a good pre-rolled gitignore file for iPhone development using Xcode and PhoneGap?

Currently I'm using:

```
.idea
.DS_Store
*.swp
*~.nib

build/
adhoc/

.xcodeproj/ !*.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj

*.mode1v3
*.mode2v3

build/

xcuserdata
```

But I'm not sure this is ideal. For example, updating Phonegap kinda messes up a lot of things. Also, if another developer just builds the project using Xcode, then git will pick up some changes.

Oddly enough, Xcode does not feature on this list: https://github.com/github/gitignore

Comment: The file [Objective-C](https://raw.github.com/github/gitignore/master/Objective-C.gitignore) is for Xcode. A related file is `echo *.pbxproj -crlf -diff -merge > .gitattributes`. It avoids merges in the pbxproj file. mode1v3 is for Xcode3, and xcuserdata is already excluded if you exclude `*.xcodeproj/*` and include back the `!*.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ended up with this .gitignore config, which worked fine:

```
.idea
.DS_Store
*.swp
*~.nib

build/
adhoc/

.xcodeproj/ !*.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj

*.mode1v3
*.mode2v3

build/

xcuserdata
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an updated version of a [sample .gitignore for Xcode iOS and OSX projects](http://blog.illuminex.com/2009/10/better-sample-gitignore-file-for-xcode.html) I made several years ago, which excludes a variety of things from the archive which are not necessary to archive, and which you might not encounter often or notice when they slip through.  It's intended to be reasonably comprehensive. It includes temp files from various editors and user preference files from Xcode and its ancestors.  (You might not encounter these often, but they show up now and then, in projects with deeper roots, or if you work with a new team member who likes a different editor.)

## Sample .gitignore for Xcode iOS and OSX projects

```
# Mac OS X Finder and whatnot 
.DS_Store
.Trashes

# Sparkle distribution Private Key
dsa_priv.pem

# Xcode (and ancestors) per-user config 
*.mode1
*.mode1v3
*.mode2v3
*.perspective
*.perspectivev3
*.pbxuser

#  Whitelist the Xcode defaults
!default.mode1
!default.mode1v3
!default.mode2v3
!default.perspective
!default.perspectivev3
!default.pbxuser

# Xcode 4 - Deprecated classes
*.moved-aside

# Xcode gcc 
*.hmap

#JetBrains AppCode
.idea/

# Generated files
VersionX-revision.h

# build products 
xcuserdata/
DerivedData/
build/
adhoc/
*.[oa]

# CocoaPods
Pods/

# Other source repository archive directories 
.hg
.svn
CVS

# automatic backup files
*~.nib
*.swp
*.lock
*~
*(Autosaved).rtfd/
Backup[ ]of[ ]*.pages/
Backup[ ]of[ ]*.key/
Backup[ ]of[ ]*.numbers/
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use Joe Blau's gitignore.io

Either through the web interfase https://www.gitignore.io/

Or by installing the CLI tool, it's very easy an fast, just type the following on your terminal:

Linux:
`echo "function gi() { curl -L -s https://www.gitignore.io/api/\$@ ;}" >> ~/.bashrc && source ~/.bashrc`

OSX:
`echo "function gi() { curl -L -s https://www.gitignore.io/api/\$@ ;}" >> ~/.bash_profile && source ~/.bash_profile`

And then you can just type `gi` followd by the all the platform/environment elements you need gitignore criteria for.

**Example!**
Lets say you're working on a node project that includes grunt and you're using webstorm on linux, then you may want to type:
`gi linux,webstorm,node,grunt > .gitignore` ( to make a brand new file)
or
`gi linux,webstorm,node,grunt >> .gitignore` ( to append/add the new rules to an existing file)

bam, you're good to go